# Sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2^n n^2)/n!$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is given that $x\cdot e^x=\sum_{n\geq 1} x^n/(n-1)!$, then the series converges to?

a. $e^2$
b. $2e^2$
c. $4e^2$
d. $6e^2$

My effort: when put $x=2$, we get $2e^2=\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^n n/n!$  but we want $\sum_{n\geq 1} 2^n\cdot n^2/n! $
So what if i simply multiply $\sum_{n\geq 1} n=n(n+1)/2$. But then I can not do so cause, $\sum x\cdot \sum y\not=\sum x\cdot y$ (correct?)
What way should I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is (d). Since $n^2=n(n-1)+n$, it follows
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n^2 }{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n(n-1)}{n!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n n}{n!}\\=4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=4e^2+2e^2=6e^2,$$
wher we used $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use $n^2=n(n-1)+n$.

So $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 }{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^n=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{n!}x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}x^{n-1}$$ that is to say $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 }{n!}x^n=x^2 \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \right)''+x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \right)'$$

If you have $n^3$ instead of $n^2$, the trick would have been $$n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+3n(n-1)+n$$ and the same method would apply.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Notice that $n^2=n(n-1)+n$, then $n^2/n!$ simplifies to

$$\frac1{(n-2)!}+\frac1{(n-1)!}.$$

After you have split the sum in two, you possibly need to adjust for the exponent of $2$ and the initial terms.